# PostGraphile NodeId identifiers for composite PrimaryKey

Tags: typescript, postgresql, postgraphile

We implemented a Postgraphile mutation plugin using method [makeExtendSchemaPlugin](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/make-extend-schema-plugin/#mutation-example-with-node-id).

In our plugin we use `NodeId` and we parse this NodeId using method `getTypeAndIdentifiersFromNodeId`. This method returns `GraphQL Type` and collection of `Identifiers`.

If our type has only one `PrimaryKey` column then we don't have any issues. We use only first element of `Identifiers` collection. And we can generate our SQL script without any troubles.

If we have **composite** `PrimaryKey` then `Identifiers` collection has multiple elements (as expected).

1. What order have elements for `Identifiers` collection?
2. Is there a correct way to define correct order (or names) of `Identifiers` elements for generation correct SQL query?

Will be grateful for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the identifiers is the same as the order of the columns in the primary key constraint in the table; for example:

```sql
create table attendance (
  module_id int not null,
  student_id int not null,
  primary key (student_id, module_id)
);
```

In this case the order of identifiers would be: student_id, module_id.

You can determine the names of the identifiers by looking at the associated columns in the primary key constraint.